# RestClient returns universal response

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I have some code:

```
public Task<IRestResponse> SendRequest(string url, string bodyJson)
{
    var client = new RestClient(url);

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.AddBody(bodyJson);

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();

    client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
    });

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

response contains all but not the answer from url (response doesnt' contain Data object). When I specify object for ExecuteAsync:

```
public Task<IRestResponse<MyClass>> SendRequest(string url, string bodyJson)
{
    var client = new RestClient(url);

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.AddBody(bodyJson);

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse<MyClass>>();

    client.ExecuteAsync<MyClass>(request, response =>
    {
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
    });

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}

public class MyClass
{
    public bool ResultCheck { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

in response I can find object Data (response.Data) which contains fields with values from url.

For example I receive response with Data: { ResultCheck=true, Message="Result!" } 
How can I receive filled Data from url with any object without specifiing type - MyClass. I wan't to receive response with any number of fields for different urls. I want to receive some anonymous object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) objects. This should allow you to specify any object type to be converted to a response.

You can therefore change the method to

```
public Task<IRestResponse<T>> SendRequest<T>(string url, string bodyJson)
{
    var client = new RestClient(url);

    var request = new RestRequest
    {
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        Method = Method.POST;
    };

    request.AddBody(bodyJson);

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse<T>>();

    client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, response =>
    {
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
    });

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Then we can create temp object using dynamic. We can then fill this will all the information we need

```
// Create temp obj
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
employee.Age = 33;
```

finally at the call site we state the type is dynamic. Hopefully the rest api can forward this onto the client and they can retrieve the object as type dynamic.

```
SendRequest<dynamic>(url, JsonConvert.SerialiseObject(employee));
```

The client can then do something like

```
dynamic response = GetResponse(...);
var name = response.Name;
```

Comment: Can I do that without generics? I don't want to create types for different urls. I gonna use return type of SendRequest() to send somewhere else. And that application doesn't know what type of object it will receive. Can I make that universally for any objects without declaring classes for them?

Comment: That's not what I need. taskCompletionSource.Task should return object which will contain Data object with all fields from url. No generic types and class declarations in both applications.

Comment: @Anton23 See above edit for how I intended it to be used. If you no class declarations at either side then we can make use of dynamic to automatically deduce us a type. I can forsee some usability issues with this however. It may be benefitial to create well know classes that can be used both to send/recieve

Comment: @Anton23 Probs best to accept the answer then to alert other people that the solution worked.